# VBA count the number of unique values

Tags: vba, excel, count-unique

I looked into the forum and I cannot really find the right answer to my problem. I have a list which looks like this:

ID             ID2

```
SS_ID 1            T1              
SS_ID 1            T2
SS_ID 1            T2
SS_ID 1            T3
SS_ID 4            T1
SS_ID 4            T5
```

There is the 1st column which has IDs. The thing is that in the second column I have also ID numbers which are related with the 1st column.

So the list is in a sheet in Excel and I am trying to find with the help of VBA the number of Users from the 2nd column who are related to the 1st column. If by any chance there is a solution without VBA please feel free to help me. But as far as I can see it I only see the solution in VBA.

FYI I generate the list from a macro.I also found a way to remove the duplicates without deleting the rows which is necessarily in my case.

To Sum up, I need the sum of "unique" values from the 2nd column which are related to the 1st column. It is like a countif function but a little more complicated.

The result should look like this:

```
SS_ID 1    =    3
SS_ID 4    =    2
```

I am completely new to VBA.

Comment: What would be the output you want to get? I mean, You explained your problem and also you posted some data as example. What would be the correct answer with the data you posted?

Comment: Hey I edited my post. i hope it helps to understand it a little bit more

Comment: Are you sure `SS_ID 1    =    2`? should not it be `SS_ID 1    =    3`? I ask these because `SS_ID 1` is related to `T1` and `T2` (twice) and `T3`. Am I right?

Comment: @DavidMorocutti Would not it be `SS_ID 1 = 3` then? Since it has `T1`, `T2`, `T3`.

Comment: Yes sorry so stupid of me......

Answer (score 3):

No need for [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) unless you absolutely require it.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("Z", A:A))=D2)/(COUNTIFS(B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("ZZZ", A:A)), B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH("ZZZ", A:A)),  A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("Z", A:A)), D2)+(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH("Z", A:A))<>D2)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a macro-based solution:

```
Sub UniqueTable()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, c As Collection, M As Long
    Dim j As Long, vd As String, va As String

    Columns("A:A").Copy Range("D1")

    ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

    Range("E1").Value = "# of unique values"

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    M = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To N
        Set c = Nothing
        Set c = New Collection
        vd = Cells(i, "D").Value
        For j = 2 To M
            va = Cells(j, "A").Value
            If va = vd Then
                On Error Resume Next
                    c.Add Cells(j, "B").Value, CStr(Cells(j, "B").Value)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next j
        Cells(i, "E").Value = c.Count
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

You can easily modify the code to place the little results table anywhere you like.  If you add/remove/modify items in cols **A** and **B**, just rerun the code.

Comment: Thank you very much i will try to implement it into my macro :)

Answer (score 0):

[Solution without VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFu8O.png)

You can use something like that:
=SUMIFS(C1:C6;A1:A6;"=SS_ID 4")

The excel funtion "SOMMA.PIU.SE" in the attached image is "SUMIFS" in english.
The SUMIFS function adds all of its arguments (A1:A6) that meet multiple criteria (A1:A6 => "=SS_ID 4").